# ask for confirmation when checking a box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i currently have a form that has several check boxes, once all the boxes are checked or left empty, it sends it to the database the state of the check boxes
i want to add, if a box is not checked, when you check it, it should ask for confirmation window "you sure you wanna check this" 
any help please?

this is the current code

```
            public IMeditor(IMui IMui, IMuser U, string User)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IMui = IMui;
        imu = U;
        if (imu.UID == 0)
        {
            Add.Text = "Add";
            imu.name = user;
        }
        else
            Add.Text = "Update";
        AuthChat.Checked = imu.AuthChat == 1;
        AuthTac1.Checked = imu.AuthTac1 == 1;
        AuthTac2.Checked = imu.AuthTac2 == 1;
        AuthTac3.Checked = imu.AuthTac3 == 1;
        AuthTac4.Checked = imu.AuthTac4 == 1;
        AuthTac5.Checked = imu.AuthTac5 == 1;
        AuthTac6.Checked = imu.AuthTac6 == 1;
        AuthTac7.Checked = imu.AuthTac7 == 1;
        AuthTac8.Checked = imu.AuthTac8 == 1;
        AuthTac9.Checked = imu.AuthTac9 == 1;
        AuthTac10.Checked = imu.AuthTac10 == 1;

        switch (imu.Transport.ToLower()) {
            case "aim":   Transport.SelectedIndex = 0; break;
            case "gtalk": Transport.SelectedIndex = 1; break;
            case "msn":   Transport.SelectedIndex = 2; break;
            case "yahoo": Transport.SelectedIndex = 3; break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to harass your users that much? Normally clicking a box just ticks or unticks the box -- exactly what the user asked for.

Comment: @sarnold its not a form a user fills out, its a form that i want to alert a user that he checked a box (only on a few) which normally shouldn't be checked (only for administrators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IMeditor(IMui IMui, IMuser U, string User)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IMui = IMui;
        imu = U;
        if (imu.UID == 0)
        {
            Add.Text = "Add";
            imu.name = user;
        }
        else
            Add.Text = "Update";
        AuthChat.Checked = imu.AuthChat == 1;
        AuthTac1.Checked = imu.AuthTac1 == 1;
        AuthTac2.Checked = imu.AuthTac2 == 1;
        AuthTac3.Checked = imu.AuthTac3 == 1;
        AuthTac4.Checked = imu.AuthTac4 == 1;
        AuthTac5.Checked = imu.AuthTac5 == 1;
        AuthTac6.Checked = imu.AuthTac6 == 1;
        AuthTac7.Checked = imu.AuthTac7 == 1;
        AuthTac8.Checked = imu.AuthTac8 == 1;
        AuthTac9.Checked = imu.AuthTac9 == 1;
        AuthTac10.Checked = imu.AuthTac10 == 1;

        switch (imu.Transport.ToLower()) {
            case "aim":   Transport.SelectedIndex = 0; break;
            case "gtalk": Transport.SelectedIndex = 1; break;
            case "msn":   Transport.SelectedIndex = 2; break;
            case "yahoo": Transport.SelectedIndex = 3; break;
        }

         AuthChat.Click += new EventHandler(ClickHandler);


    }

 void ClickHandler(Object obj, EventArgs args)
        { 
if (obj == AuthChat && AuthChat.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to change?", "are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);        

                if (result == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    AuthChat.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Izzy.  Add something like

```
    private void PrivateInitialize()
    {

        CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
        chkBox.Text = "Click me";
        chkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkBox_CheckedChanged);
    }

    private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nag, nag, nag!  You take out the trash yet?");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the event CheckedChangedEvent for the checkbox. You can find the sample code on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx). Also

[this link for the complete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) understanding of checkbox.

Or else you can derive your own class from CheckBox control of windows forms then override the  required function and implement your own logic and create all the checkboxes in your application from this derived class

Comment: im sorry, im kid of a newbie
so ill need a little more help on how to do it, maybe someone can edit my code i am using? or tell me step-by-step what i have to do

Answer (score 0):

```
public IMeditor(IMui IMui, IMuser U, string User)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.IMui = IMui;
        imu = U;
        if (imu.UID == 0)
        {
            Add.Text = "Add";
            imu.name = user;
        }
        else
            Add.Text = "Update";
        AuthChat.Checked = imu.AuthChat == 1;
        AuthTac1.Checked = imu.AuthTac1 == 1;
        AuthTac2.Checked = imu.AuthTac2 == 1;
        AuthTac3.Checked = imu.AuthTac3 == 1;
        AuthTac4.Checked = imu.AuthTac4 == 1;
        AuthTac5.Checked = imu.AuthTac5 == 1;
        AuthTac6.Checked = imu.AuthTac6 == 1;
        AuthTac7.Checked = imu.AuthTac7 == 1;
        AuthTac8.Checked = imu.AuthTac8 == 1;
        AuthTac9.Checked = imu.AuthTac9 == 1;
        AuthTac10.Checked = imu.AuthTac10 == 1;

        switch (imu.Transport.ToLower()) {
            case "aim":   Transport.SelectedIndex = 0; break;
            case "gtalk": Transport.SelectedIndex = 1; break;
            case "msn":   Transport.SelectedIndex = 2; break;
            case "yahoo": Transport.SelectedIndex = 3; break;
        }

         AuthChat.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckChangedHandler);
         AuthChat1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckChangedHandler);

    }

 void CheckChangedHandler(Object obj, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (obj == AuthChat)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Checked changed for AuthChat");
            }
            else if (obj == AuthChat1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Checked changed for AuthChat1");
            }
        }
```

Comment: it now alerts me, whats if i would rather have it as a Yes or No box? so it asks you sure you want to check this box, and its only when checking it.. if un checking it, then i dont care for a message window

Comment: I have posted the new answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

do it with javascript? add OnClientClick="return confirmCheck(this);"

```
<script language="javascript">
function confirmCheck(e){
 return confirm("are you sure?");
 // do other stuff
}
</script>
```

this should be better than redirecting people

Comment: This is winforms applicaiton. Where does javascript come into the picture?